# parsing a string into an object for posting

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I need a up a way to parse a string, loop through it, add elements of that into an object and do a post with it.

Our legacy form only takes in a parameter "letters", we don't want to have to change anything there.

eg.

```
 <form>
     <input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="a" />
     <input type="checkbox" name="letters" value="b" />
 </form>

 var msg = "x;y;z";
 var a = msg.split(';');
 for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 .....
```

What type of object would I use and how would I append it into this format?

```
 someobj = { letters: a, letters: b, letters: c }
```

Is this even efficient?

this would then be used to do a 
     $.post('/', someobj, function() { });

which would be doing

```
 $.post('/', { letters: a, letters: b, letters: c }, function() { });
```

Or is there a simpler way if any?

Comment: That's not a valid object.  You can't have 3 of the same key.  Perhaps you wanted: `someobj = {letters: msg.split(';')}`?

Comment: Re what Rocket said, if you actually do `someobj = { letters: a, letters: b, letters: c }`, you'll find that in loose mode, the result is an object with **one** property, `letters`, with the value from `c`. (In strict mode, it's an error.)

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to submit an array, you already have most of your code:

```
var msg = "x;y;z";
var a = msg.split(';');
$.post(url,
    {letters: a},
    function ( jsonResults ) {
        // ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do this:

```
someobj = { letters: "a", letters: "b", letters: "c" }
```

result will be:

```
someobj = { letters: "c" }
```

because, you are replacing the `letters` key of this object again and again anyway.

I will suggest to keep this comma separated in array only like:

```
someobj = { letters: msg.split(";")}
```

---

Or, send it as string within that object, 
**This will do something like:**

```
someobj = { letters: msg.split(";").join(",")}
```

or

```
someobj = { letters: msg.replace(/\;/g, ",")}
```